# How to extract value from JSON Path extractor based on condition

Tags: json, jmeter, json-path-expression

I would like to get the value of the  "currentApproversStr:" based on the condition "status":"Ready for Review" from the below JSON Response body of a HTTP sampler and pass to following HTTP sampler.

**I tried the below but it's not working**

1. Names of created variables: currentApproversStr
2. JSON Path expressions: $.[?((@.currentApproversStr == "Validation, Civa" ||  @.currentApproversStr == "Validation, Darla" ||  @.currentApproversStr == "Validation, Bittl"  ||  @.currentApproversStr == "Validation, Cha"  ||  @.currentApproversStr == "Validation, Barnett" ) && @.status== "Ready for Review")]
3. Match No: -1 OR 1

**But Dummy Sampler returns the Results**

We can't guarantee the order of the  "timecardId" block with the  "status":"Ready for Review" i.e some times 2 nd place, some times last. In this it's 2nd block.  So not sure Match No: what should i give
[image]

```
[
  {
    "timecardId": 170803,
    "entryHeaderId": "db9341a9-32e8-4d45-a858-a88b75a42cef",
    "startsOn": "2021-10-24T00:00:00",
    "endsOn": "2021-10-30T00:00:00",
    "worksightStatus": "SignedOff",
    "projectId": 1977,
    "userId": 60874,
    "status": "Submitted for Approval",
    "batchId": 39814,
    "emergencyType": "",
    "htgDealMemoId": "0d0ff42b-5c4b-4695-b527-34dfc64585e5",
    "unionId": "1c77c660-28fc-4e40-b557-132f3da39597",
    "currentApproversStr": "Perf, PA",
    "commentStr": "",
    "commentUserName": "",
    "commentCreatedAt": "1900-01-01T00:00:00",
    "occupationCode": "TECHNICIAN",
    "activeApprovalFlowId": 166669,
    "isAllowanceOnly": false,
    "departmentId": null,
    "datePosted": null
  },
  {
    "timecardId": 170807,
    "entryHeaderId": "c9809446-b01f-4f42-add6-9b441c3d0114",
    "startsOn": "2021-10-17T00:00:00",
    "endsOn": "2021-10-23T00:00:00",
    "worksightStatus": "Outstanding",
    "projectId": 1977,
    "userId": 60874,
    "status": "Ready for Review",
    "batchId": 39815,
    "emergencyType": "",
    "htgDealMemoId": "0d0ff42b-5c4b-4695-b527-34dfc64585e5",
    "unionId": "1c77c660-28fc-4e40-b557-132f3da39597",
    "currentApproversStr": "Validation, Civa",
    "commentStr": "",
    "commentUserName": "",
    "commentCreatedAt": "1900-01-01T00:00:00",
    "occupationCode": "TECHNICIAN",
    "activeApprovalFlowId": 166674,
    "isAllowanceOnly": false,
    "departmentId": null,
    "datePosted": null
  },
  {
    "timecardId": 170802,
    "entryHeaderId": "db9341a9-32e8-4d45-a858-a88b75a42cef",
    "startsOn": "2021-10-24T00:00:00",
    "endsOn": "2021-10-30T00:00:00",
    "worksightStatus": "SignedOff",
    "projectId": 1977,
    "userId": 60874,
    "status": "Submitted for Approval",
    "batchId": 39814,
    "emergencyType": "",
    "htgDealMemoId": "0d0ff42b-5c4b-4695-b527-34dfc64585e5",
    "unionId": "1c77c660-28fc-4e40-b557-132f3da39597",
    "currentApproversStr": "Perf, PA",
    "commentStr": "",
    "commentUserName": "",
    "commentCreatedAt": "1900-01-01T00:00:00",
    "occupationCode": "TECHNICIAN",
    "activeApprovalFlowId": 166669,
    "isAllowanceOnly": false,
    "departmentId": null,
    "datePosted": null
  }
]
```

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PROBLEM:**
The reason is that you misunderstand the way JSON extractor works. This feature allows you extract many variables in one setting, but number of `Names of created variables` = number of `JSON Path expressions` = number of `Default Values`.

For example, you want to extract 2 variables:

- Names of created variables: `var_name_1`; `var_name_2`
- JSON Path expressions: `json_expression_1`; `json_expression_2`
- Default Values: `default_1`; `default_2`

(Note: remember using semicolon (;) to separate values)

But you set **1** Variable, **1** json expression with **MANY** default values  --> mismatch.

**SOLUTION:**
You can setup like this:

```
Names of created variables: currentApproversStr
JSON Path expressions: $.[?(@.status== "Ready for Review")].currentApproversStr
Match No: -1
Default Values: NOT_FOUND
```

Result:

```
currentApproversStr_1=Validation, Civa
currentApproversStr_matchNr=1
```

Comment: It's returns the results, but not replacing the value in the following request. Not able to figured it out what went wrong. See the attached screenshots

Comment: @rpagadala If `Match No: -1` and only one match --> var_name will be `currentApproversStr_1`. You can change `Match No: -1` --> `Match No: 1`, then get the var_name is `currentApproversStr`

Comment: @lucsnaguyen It worked! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

"Match No" works as follows: if your query returns more than 1 result:

1. `0` - returns random result
2. `-1` - returns ALL results in form of:

   - `currentApproversStr_1` - first match
   - `currentApproversStr_2` - second match
   - etc.
   - `currentApproversStr_matchNr` - total number of matches
3. `any positive integer` - returns the given match

It applies not only to [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) but to all other [JMeter PostProcessors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) which extract values from responses.

You can see generated [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script):

[image]